# Facebook SDK, when user likes and comments the post we get any response to from which we posted this post?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

When user posts the any post from the app, then he wants to get count of the likes and comments of post I get that all count,
but my question is when any one likes the post, Facebook provides any type of trigger on my server (can I get Automatically response of that post on my server.? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks).

> The Graph API has a feature called Webhooks (formerly known as Real
>   Time Updates) that enables apps to subscribe to changes in certain
>   pieces of data and receive updates in real time

If you cannot find what you are looking for there then it probably is not possible.

Comment: Hello Tom...!!!
                      Can you clear me I have doubt, I Post the one video on Facebook, now I want like and comment count of that post.
                      And I got that, but only when I fire the request from my app, so my question is  Can I get it ( like/comment  count ) without open my app (get the notification).
                      When some one like/comment I got the notification.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a webhook (see answer above) subscription on "videos" ? We won't do the work for you you need to try things, Stack Overflow is about debugging code not writing it from scratch.